# JScrollPane doesn't appear

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I would like to create a `JscrollPane` jsp in my panel `panneau`. But This `JscroolPane` doesn't appear. I think the trouble is that I use `setLayout` to `null`.

The code might produce a layout like this, the number of rows & columns of text fields are variable (in constructor):

[image: layout]

That's my code :

```
public class Cadre_fenetreA3 extends JFrame 
{
    JButton boutonOK = new JButton ("OK");
    public Cadre_fenetreA3 (String nom,int X, int Y, int lo, int la, int nbligne,int nbcolonne,String[] nomGrpGen, int Na, File file, boolean dernier)      
    {

        super(nom);                     
        setBounds(X,Y,500,500);     
        setVisible(true);   
        setFocusable(true);

        JLabel phrase = new JLabel("<html>Veuillez indiquer l'appartenance ou non d'un attribut <br> a un groupe d'attribut du Niveau :</html>"+Na);
        JTextField[][] allField = new JTextField [nbligne][nbcolonne];
        JLabel phrases[] = new JLabel [nbligne];
        JPanel panneau = new JPanel();
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(panneau);

        jsp.createVerticalScrollBar(); 
        jsp.createHorizontalScrollBar(); 
            jsp.setBounds(20,20, 20, 20);
        panneau.setLayout(null);

        for(int i = 0;i < nbligne;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j<nbcolonne;j++)
            {
                int random = (int)(Math.random()*2);
                 allField[i][j] = new JTextField(String.valueOf(random));
                 allField[i][j].setBounds(150+j * 30, 75 + i * 30, 20, 20);
                 panneau.add(allField[i][j]);
            }

           phrases[i] = new JLabel(nomGrpGen[i]);
           phrases[i].setBounds(5, 75+ i * 30, 200, 20);

          panneau.add( phrases[i]);
        }
        phrase.setBounds(0,0,1000,50);
         panneau.add(phrase);

        boutonOK.setBounds(lo-90,la-110,60,60);
        boutonOK.addActionListener(new ecout(nbligne,nbcolonne,allField, file, dernier));
         panneau.add(boutonOK);
         add(jsp);
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add `jsp` instead of `panneau` in the last line?

Comment: I have added a screen shot of what I suspect the GUI is expected to look like as far as layout goes.  Perhaps the question would be "how do I make this dynamic layout with a scroll-pane using layouts?".  Though I gave 2 answers to that question in a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's because you're adding `panneau` at the end - you should be adding `jsp` ;-)

Also, don't set the `LayoutManager` to `null` because that will cause problems (unless you know what you're doing). For your requirements, everything you need can be found in the [Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: The edited code still uses a `null` layout.  **Use layouts to avoid these type of quirks.**  A nested layout with the help label in the `PAGE_START` of a `BorderLayout` a single column `GridLayout` in the `LINE_START` for the group labels, and a WxH `GridLayout` in the `CENTER` for the text fields.  Put the button in a `FlowLayout` in the `PAGE_END`.  Either that lot or use a `GroupLayout`.

Comment: See also the screen-shot now edited into the question.  +1 for 'use layout'. :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson : +1 for using those `PAGE_START/LINE_START/CENTER/LINE_END/PAGE_END` for `BorderLayout` :-)

Comment: @Gagandeep (Chuckle) To those who say "Old dogs cannot learn new tricks" I say "Woof-woof, ...grrrr".